# For Deleting incoming and Outgoing link in doors

Tags: ibm-doors

How can we delete incoming or outgoing links for a particular objects from a particular modules through dxl script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to edit your question to include the steps and code you've already tried and the problems you faced with them

Answer (score 1):

this code is for deleting every incoming and outgoing links for all objects from current module. It is not tested, but you can start from here.

```
Object o
Link lk
for o in current Module do
{
    for lk in o -> "*" do // for outcoming links
    {
        delete(lk)
    }
    for lk in o <- "*" do  // for incoming links
    {
        delete(lk)
    }
 }
```

**Advice: When you ask something post what you tried to do in order to solve the problem.**

**EDIT:**

This code is tested and deletes outcoming and incoming links from a specified object from a specified module.

```
Folder f = current
Module m
string object_id = <hardcoded_id_or_from_somewhere>
string module_name = <same_as_object_id>
for m in f do
{
    if(name(m) == module_name)
    {
        Object o
        for o in m do
        {
            if(identifier(o) == object_id)
            {
                Link lk
                for lk in o -> "*" do // for outcoming links
                {
                    delete(lk)
                }
                for lk in o <- "*" do  // for incoming links
                {
                    delete(lk)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, I want to delete links for a particular module for particular object id. It means for example: For  a source module it has three target modules. From three target modules I want delete the link only from one module. For that module I want delete that link which I will give object ID.

Comment: As I said, this piece of code is a good start, now you have just to verify the object ID from your specific module name. All the best!

Comment: I already tried this code previously, it delete all the incoming and outgoing links for a module. I only want for a particular module for specific object.

Comment: Ok, so you have the module name and the object ID in 2 variables...I will make an Edit, tell me if that is what you need.